# How to set permission to FAT32 USB pen drive in windows c/c++?

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, fat32

I want to restrict access to USB devices to prevent read/write access.

For NTFS file system I have done with Access Control List(ACL) but for FAT32 file system there is no ACL.

so how to restrict access for FAT32 file system devices?

Any help/idea?

Thanks a lot.

Language c/c++